# How do I display a help text with field form?

Tags: 8, forms

Is there a way to bring up a help message next to a form field as below?

*FooForm.php*

```
$form['field_foo'] = array(
    '#type'          => 'textfield',
    '#title'         => t('Foo'),
    '#required'      => true,
    '#default_value' => 'foo',
    '#help_text' => 'Help text for Foo field',
);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use **#description** attribute.

```
$form['field_foo'] = array(
  '#type'          => 'textfield',
  '#title'         => t('Foo'),
  '#required'      => true,
  '#default_value' => 'foo',
  '#description' => t('Help text for Foo field'), 
);
```